# How to use the start and expiration date of a promotion from a CodeIgniter database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to get the `start_date` and the `expire_date` of a `promotion` from a CodeIgniter database, such that the promotion automatically appears on the `start_date` and disappears after the `expire_date`.
How can I achieve this?

This is the layout of the database :

```
promotion:
id(primary,autmatic),
image(varchar,255),
description(longtext),
start_date(datetime),
expire_date(datetime),
```

An example of the contents is as follows:

```
id image description start_date expired_date
1  1.jpg textpromo1   1/10/2015 5/10/2015  
2  2.jpg textpromo2   8/10/2015 22/10/2015
2  3.jpg textpromo3   1/11/2015 12/11/2015
```

And this is my query code in the view

```
<?php $query = $this->db->get('promotion'); ?>
<?php foreach($query->result() as $val): ?>
<div class="promotion">
<p><?php echo image; ?></p>
<p><?php echo description; ?></p>
<p><?php echo start_date; ?></p>
<p><?php echo expired_date; ?></p>
 </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which results in:

```
 1.jpg textpromo1   1/10/2015 5/10/2015  
  2.jpg textpromo2   8/10/2015 22/10/2015
  3.jpg textpromo3   1/11/2015 12/11/2015
```

Comment: what is the expected output?? you want to fetch todays gate is less that expiry date and greater than start date??

Comment: Example I want to star at 1/10/2015 and end 10/10/2015

Comment: ok but how you want to fetch the data?? please elobarate a bit.

Comment: or other promotion 12/10/2015 to 20/10/2015

Comment: But before I never do it could u help me pleas ?

Comment: you are not clarifing what you want. you are just telling the requirement.

Comment: I want my promotion start apear and my promotion end it is disapear automatic

Comment: Could u help me please :(

Comment: we will help you, you want to fetch todays gate is less that expiry date and greater than start date??

Comment: and my english so weak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, you want to fetch records between start and expiry date

```
SELECT * 
FROM promotion 
WHERE start_date <= '2015-10-23' AND expire_date >= '2015-10-23'
```

In codeigniter do like this,

```
 <?php 
   $this->db->where('start_date <= ' , date('Y-m-d')); 
   $this->db->where('expired_date >= ' , date('Y-m-d')); 
 ?>
```

You can take today's date in some variable and use in query.

Comment: Ok thz q Niranjan N Raju I will test it

Comment: Hi Niranjan sorry not today some day that the customer want promotion

Comment: Its mean some day tha I want to promotion

Comment: I did this code but I got blank page $this->db->where('start_date >= ' , date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('expire_date <= ' , date('Y-m-d'));
$query = $this->db->get('promotion');

Comment: Your code WHERE start_date >= '2015-10-23' AND expire_date <= '2015-10-23' I dont want this day .I want some day That I want

Comment: start date <= and expiredate >=

Comment: Edit ur answer now I will accapt

Comment: Yes Edit ur answer to <?php $this->db->where('start_date <= ' , date('Y-m-d')); ?>
 <?php $this->db->where('expired_date >= ' , date('Y-m-d')); ?>

Comment: Very thz Nirajan N Raju u . for helpfull very thz :D

Answer (score 0):

Use where condition like bellow.

```
$this->db->where('start_date >= ' , date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('expire_date <= ' , date('Y-m-d'));
$query = $this->db->get('promotion');
```

> **You will get more information here**
>
> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I did ur follow but it is blank page .

Comment: that's because your date in database is in format 'd-m-Y' and the where statement is in format 'Y-m-d' so they don't match. MySQL date format is (Y-m-d) so I would change them both to match it